# How to exclude getters from class to create repository?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript

I have this class:

```
export class User{
    fName: string;
    lName: string;
    get FullName() { return this.fName + ' ' + this.lName }
}
```

And i create collection of `User`:

```
cost userRepo = this.connection.db(db).collection<User>(db)
```

the problem is that when i do `userRepo.find({})` I can sent `FullName` as parameter.

So, my question is , there is easy way to create new type from existing class, exclude getter/setter? (without create interface or base class... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really distinguish properties from getter/setters at the type level.  So the short answer to your question is "no", as others have stated.

A *possible* way forward for you is to note that a property with a getter but no setter ends up being treated as [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#readonly-properties).   And it turns out that you *can* make a type function that pulls out `readonly` properties, using some crazy type manipulation magic:

```
// detect if two types X and Y are exactly identical
type IfEquals<X, Y, A=X, B=never> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

// writable keys are those which are exactly equal when you strip readonly off
// in a mapped type
type WritableKeys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, P>
}[keyof T];
```

And the type you're looking for:

```
type UserWithoutGetters = Pick<User, WritableKeys<User>>;
// type UserWithoutGetters = {
//   fName: string;
//   lName: string;
// }
```

Does that help?  Good luck!

Comment: Yes! thanks.what is the meaning of hyphen in '[P in keyof T]-' and  -readonly?

Comment: It [removes modifiers from mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The class is just a blueprint of the object you are about to create. The above class will just be compiled into a function constructor in javascript and will always include all the properties initially given to it.

Comment: I searching of something like keyof, just without getter/setter https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html,

Comment: It's not the same. This will help you combine different types, but not exclude any of their properties